# Can every differential equation be expressed in function notation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I often find differential equation written in function notation:

[image]

I know it might be a trivial question,but....

Is this notation possible for every differential equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

An equation is just a function of several variables $f(x,y,z,w,t,\cdots,k)$ set equal to zero, or even a constant.

For a differential equation, the variables include derivatives (partial or ordinary) of other variables.